# Scala equivalent of `??` operator in C#

Tags: c#, scala

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to write a proper null-safe coalescing operator in scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1364361/how-to-write-a-proper-null-safe-coalescing-operator-in-scala)

What is the Scala equivalent of `??` operator in C#?

example:

```
string result = value1 ?? value2 ?? value3 ?? String.Empty;
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1364361/how-to-write-a-proper-null-safe-coalescing-operator-in-scala ?

Answer (score 10):

You can write your own with identical semantics--here's one that insists on the same type throughout due to left-to-right evaluation, but one could change it to ?: to get right-to-left evaluation that would widen types as needed:

```
class CoalesceNull[A <: AnyRef](a: A) { def ??(b: A) = if (a==null) b else a }
implicit def coalesce_anything[A <: AnyRef](a: A) = new CoalesceNull(a)

scala> (null:String) ?? (null:String) ?? "(default value)"
res0: String = (default value)
```

But the reason why this operator doesn't exist may be that `Option` is the preferred way of dealing with such scenarios as well as many similar cases of handling of non-existent values:

```
scala> List((null:String),(null:String),"(default value)").flatMap(Option(_)).headOption
res72: Option[java.lang.String] = Some((default value))
```

(If you were sure that at least one was non-null, you could just use `head`; note that this works because `Option(null)` converts to `None` and `flatMap` gathers together only the `Some(_)` entries.)

Comment: I believe it should be `def ??(b: => A)` to make the semantics identical. I think the right side of the elvis operator should not be evaluated unless `a` is `null`. May be wrong though.

Comment: @sinharaj - You're probably right.  I'm not that familiar with how C# does this.

Answer (score 5):

Try getOrElse. My friend suggested.

Comment: Not a proper operator but could be handy for simple expressions:
`Option(null:String).getOrElse("default value")`  or  `Option(Option(null:String).getOrElse(null:String)).getOrElse("default value")`

Answer (score 2):

I dont believe there is one.  You can see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1364361/how-to-write-a-proper-null-safe-coalescing-operator-in-scala) post for an implementation of the null coalescing operator.

Answer (score 2):

See linked answer, but, more to the point, avoids nulls. Use Option.

Answer (score 1):

[This blog post](http://www.codecommit.com/blog/scala/implementing-groovys-elvis-operator-in-scala) covers how to implement Groovy's "Elvis operator `?:`" in Scala.  This does the same thing as C#'s `??` operator.